# Where does the $-k\delta$ part of the expression for weights come from?

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider the affine Lie algebra with the Cartan matrix 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -2\\
-2 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$
Let $\omega_{0}$ be the zeroth fundamental weight, $\alpha_1$ the first root, and $\delta$ the imaginary root.
We wish to prove that the weights of irreducible highest weight module $L\left(\omega_{0}\right)$ are
$$
\left\{ \omega_{0}+n\alpha_{1}-n^{2}\delta-k\delta|n\in\mathbb{Z},k\ge0\right\} (1)
$$

Here is the issue: I have easily proved that
$$
\left\{ \omega_{0}+n\alpha_{1}-n^{2}\delta|n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\} (2)
$$
are weights by applying the Weyl group with basis $s_0,s_1$ to $\omega_0$.

In particular, any $w\in W$ can be expressed in form $\left(s_{0}s_{1}\right)^{n},n\ge0$ or $s_{0}\left(s_{0}s_{1}\right)^{n},n\ge0$. We have that
$$
\left(s_{0}s_{1}\right)^{\mathbb N}\omega_0=\left\{ \omega_{0}+n\alpha_{1}-n^{2}\delta|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
and further
$$
s_{0}\left(s_{0}s_{1}\right)^{\mathbb N}\omega_0=\left\{ \omega_{0}+\left(1-n\right)\alpha_{1}-\left(1-n\right)^{2}\delta|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
which essentially proves (2).

I am obviously missing something very trivial to expand the expression (2) to the required expression (1) for weights, which includes $-k\delta$ as well. I have looked for this bit in textbooks of Kac and Fuchs, but did not find it.
I would appreciate a pointer to complete the problem solution.

Is there perhaps an analogue $\sigma$ of a Weil group basis element for imaginary root, which acts on it as $\sigma\left(j\delta\right)=\left(j-1\right)\delta\forall j\in\mathbb{Z}$?